# How to arrange output in a ascending order?

Tags: java

So I wrote code to read from a file and do some calculations, and produce an output like this:

```
First Name = tony
Last Name = wroten
Geometric Mean = 663002.7727000846
----------------------------

First Name = nick
Last Name = young
Geometric Mean 128740.18176156192
```

But its just an Output and is not stored anywhere. Is there a way to arrange the output in ascending order according to Geometric Mean?

Comment: How about [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)?

Comment: if you want to sort it, you should store it in a container, data structure, collection or whatever you wanna call it, then sort the collection and print it. it is not only the easiest way, it is also the best for performance

Comment: Two choices: 1) Modify your program to a) compute the results, b) save each result into a list (e.g. "ArrayList" in the example below), and finally c) print the list in sorted order ... OR ... 2) Use a pipe, e.g. `java myprog | sort` to sort the program's stdout.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a holder for your file information. For example PersonVO as per my code below.
- Your logic of reading the file and setting the values for the person may change. I have just given an example.
- Once that is done, add each person to a list
- Then sort the list
- Since the sorting is based on a particular attribute, we have to create a **Custom Comparator** which is PersonComparator as per my example below

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {


              PersonVO person1 = new PersonVO("firstname1", "lastname1", 2.1);
              PersonVO person2 = new PersonVO("firstname2", "lastname2", 1.1);

              List<PersonVO> personList = new ArrayList<PersonVO>();
              personList.add(person1);
              personList.add(person2);

              System.out.println("Before Sort");
              System.out.println(personList);

              Collections.sort(personList, new PersonComparator());
              System.out.println("After Sort");
              System.out.println(personList);
          }
  ```

This is a sample implementation for the VO that holds the information for each person read from the file to a class.

```
public class PersonVO {


    public PersonVO(String firstName, String lastName, double mean) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.mean = mean;
    }
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double mean;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public double getMean() {
        return mean;
    }
    public void setMean(double mean) {
        this.mean = mean;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PersonVO [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                + ", mean=" + mean + "]";
    }


}
```

And below is an implementation of the Comparator

```
import java.util.Comparator;


    public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<PersonVO> {

        @Override
        public int compare(PersonVO p1, PersonVO p2) {
            return Double.valueOf(p1.getMean()).compareTo(Double.valueOf(p2.getMean()));
        }

    }
```